# OpenCV in Ubuntu does not show window

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, ubuntu, eclipse-cdt

I installed a fresh Ubuntu. Downloaded Eclipse via the Shop, installed the CDT plugin via the Plugin Manager in Eclipse (Kepler). I used the Shop to download the OpenCV dev package. After adding the paths in eclipse I wrote a short program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cvNamedWindow( "result", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1);

    IplImage *newImg;

    while(true)
    {
        newImg = cvQueryFrame( capture );
        if( newImg==0 )
            break;
        cvShowImage( "result", newImg );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program compiles and the debugger shows some values in newImg. But there is no window coming up and shows the result. The camera LED lights, a step through the loop seem to work perfect. Only the output window is missing. The same program runs perfect in XCode on OS X.

Comment: you're not using the c++ opencvAPI, make your life easier and use the c++ functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add small wait between execution of subsequent loops. Use `cv::waitKey` for this purpose.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cvNamedWindow( "result", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1);

    IplImage *newImg;

    while(true)
    {
        newImg = cvQueryFrame( capture );
        if( newImg==0 )
            break;
        cvShowImage( "result", newImg );
        cv::waitKey(100); //Wait of 100 ms
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: THX. cv::waitKey seems do be also a kind of MessagePump. I found a similar solution with cvStartWindowThread at any position in the code. But I think your solution is better.